# Why does gdb show a different parameter order for a function

Tags: gdb

Looking through a core file(generated by C code) with `gdb`, I am unable to understand one particular thing between these 2 frames

```
#2  increment_counter (nsteps=2, steps=0x7f3fbad26790) at gconv_db.c:393
#3  find_derivation (...) at gconv_db.c:426
```

This code is from open source `glibc` where `find_derivation` calls `increment_counter` as:

```
result = increment_counter (*handle, *nsteps);
```

The `*handle` and `steps` are of the same type and `increment_counter` function is defined as `static`

Why does `gdb` show that the 2 parameters have different order ?

I am pretty sure that `glibc` was taken as is without modification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does gdb show that the 2 parameters have different order ?

GDB doesn't know *anything* about the source (except possibly where on disk it was located at build time).

It is able to display parameters (and their values) because the *compiler* told it (by embedding debug info into the object file) what parameters are, in what order they appear, their types, and how to compute their value.

So why would a compiler re-order function arguments?

The function is `static`, so it can't be called from outside of the current translation unit. Thus the compiler *is free* to re-order the parameters, so long as it also re-orders the arguments at every call site.

Still, why would it do that? General answer: optimization (compiler found it more convenient to pass them in this order). Detailed answer would require digging into GCC (or whatever compiler was used to build this code) source.

Comment: That is exactly what I had suspected :) Thanks for explaining this